# How to rename multiple columns in pandas dataframe in one go?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
   _Ab  _Bc   C    D   _Ef  _Fg
0   a    4    7    1    5    a
1   b    5    8    3    3    a
2   c    4    9    5    6    a
3   d    5    4    7    9    b
4   e    5    2    1    2    b
5   f    4    3    0    4    b
```

I want to remove the starting `_` present in some of the column names. Obviously I can replace them one at a time but that would be very inefficient as I have a lot of columns. So how can I do this efficiently?

Comment: What is number of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `if-else` and `startswith`:

```
df.columns = [x.lstrip('_') if x.startswith('_') else x for x in df.columns]
```

Another solutions try left strip `_` from all columns:

```
df.columns = [x.lstrip('_') for x in df.columns]
```

Or with [`Index.str.lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('_')
```

Or with `rename`:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.lstrip('_'))
print (df)
  Ab  Bc  C  D  Ef Fg
0  a   4  7  1   5  a
1  b   5  8  3   3  a
2  c   4  9  5   6  a
3  d   5  4  7   9  b
4  e   5  2  1   2  b
5  f   4  3  0   4  b
```

Comment: Tried your code, but I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @Ank - Do you try `df.columns = df.columns.lstrip('_')` instead `df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('_')`  - missing `str`?

Comment: Now I am getting AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Comment: You're failing to type the StringMethods accessor. Instead of writing `df.columns.lstrip(.)` write `df.columns.str.lstrip(.)` (full stop in method invocation standing in for assorted parameters)

Comment: @Ank - how working first solution `df.columns = [x.lstrip('_') if x.startswith('_') else x for x in df.columns]` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```py
df.columns = [c.lstrip("_") for c in df.columns]
```